# Use ndb IN operator in query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to use ndb operator "IN" in a way, that I would search for a value in model's array?

For example

```
foo_1.array_of_values = ["item1", "item2"]
foo_1.put()
```

I would like to query like:

```
Foo.query("item2" in Foo.array_of_values)
```

So, is that even possible? Is there any workaround?

I don't want to fetch all entities and then filter them by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `array_of_values` is a `ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)` then a regular equality filter will do the trick `Foo.query(Foo.array_of_values == "item2")`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#repeated_properties

Comment: @Alex is there also other way around? Let's suppose You have `Foo.email` and you want to check if it can be found in `['email1', 'email2']` or something like this.